# How can I make my website expand fluidly when I add new content?

Tags: html, css, css-position

Currently, when I add a line or two of text, everything that comes below the text within the div overlaps with the div below. I believe this is a positioning issue. What do I have to do so that I can add new content w/o worrying about divs overlapping?

Comment: Can you give us an example of your code? That would help :)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the item you are adding content to either has a `height` or `max-height` value set to it in CSS. If you remove those, it will allow the div to expand instead of running out.

Be careful though, as this might make other elements go wonky which will also need to be adjusted.

Answer (score 0):

Use Samanime's answer, and to make navigation easier, set overflow=y: scroll or auto, so as long as contents overlaps the height you defined, the scrollbar will make possible to go around inside div. Like this:

```
<div style="max-height: 300px; overflow-y: auto;"> yourstuff </div>
```